# Without loss of generatity in the Proposition 2.6 from Conway's complex book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book and on page 70 he stated that we can assume $a=0$ and $r=1$.

[image]

I didn't understand why we can assume this without loss of generality. I've tried to make some substitutions on the proposition using $g(z)$ without success.

Answer (score 2):

First, suppose that $\bar{B}(a;r) \subset G$ and let $z_0 \in \bar{B}(0;1)$, then $rz_0+a \in G$ (because $rz_0+a \in \bar{B}(a;r)$) and we get that $z_0 \in G_1$ ($\bar{B}(0;1) \subset G_1$).

Conversely, if $\bar{B}(0;1) \subset G_1$ and $z_0 \in \bar{B}(a;r)$, then $\frac{z_0-a}{r} \in \bar{B}(0;1) \subset G_1$ which, by definition of $G_1$, implies that $z_0 \in G$ ($\bar{B}(a;r) \subset G$).

Now, let $z',w'$ and $\gamma'$ be such that
$$
z=rz'+a\\
w=rw'+a\\
\gamma'=e^{it}, \qquad t\in[0,2\pi],
$$
and suppose that, for any $z' \in B(0;1)$
$$
f(z')=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma'} \frac{f(w')}{w'-z'}dw'.
$$

Then,
$$
f(z)=f(rz'+a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f\left(\frac{w-a}{r}r+a\right)}{\frac{w-a}{r}-\frac{z-a}{r}}\frac{1}{r}dw=\\
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw.
$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! I have a question, why can you replace $\gamma'$ by $\gamma$ in the last lines?

Comment: The reason for that is the change in the variable in order to which we're integrating now. Note that in the end we're integrating in order to w (as opposed to w') and as w=rw'+a substituting \gamma' for w' we get \gamma. Best wishes.